# sql The multi-part identifier could not be bound sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have that error with execute "The multi-part identifier "od.Ordernumber" could not be bounds"
"The multi-part identifier "od.Location_code" could not be bounds"

```
create function Mbse.udf_ordertotal
(@Numberoforder int , @loction_code int )
returns int 
as
begin

declare @amount as int 

set @amount=(select  sum(od.amount) from Mbse.OrderDetails as od 
where (@Numberoforder=od.Ordernumber and @loction_code=od.Location_code) 
)
return @amount
end

alter table Mbse.orders
add amount as Mbse.udf_ordertotal(Mbse.OrderDetails.Ordernumber , Mbse.OrderDetails.location_code)
```

i expect solve for this problem please

Comment: What does the `Mbse.OrderDetails` table structure look like? Are you sure the column names are correct?

Comment: This cannot be done the way you are attempting - you cannot reference the OrderDetails table from the computed column on the Orders table.  It looks like you are trying to create a total amounts column for the Order based on the order items (details) for the order.  That is a really bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

Like Jeff said in the comments, your computed column using a user-defined function to aggregate the `Mbse.OrderDetails` table is not a good idea for multiple reasons. It'll be heavy, will process RBAR (row by agonizing row) aka once per every row, and will [prevent parallelism](https://straightforwardsql.com/posts/scary-scalar-functions-parallelism/) for any queries that reference that function or your `Mbse.orders` table directly or even indirectly.

You'd be better off with proper indexing on your `OrderDetails` table and a view that joins it to your `Orders` table like so:

```
-- Columnstore indexes are typically very quick for aggregative queries
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX IX_OrderDetails_Amount ON Mbse.OrderDetails (Ordernumber, Location_code, amount);

CREATE VIEW Mbse.OrdersWithTotals 
AS

WITH _OrderDetailsTotals AS
(
    SELECT
        Ordernumber, 
        Location_code, 
        SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM Msbe.OrderDetails
    GROUP BY 
        Ordernumber, 
        Location_code
)

SELECT
    O.Ordernumber,
    O.location_code,
    ODT.TotalAmount
FROM Mbse.orders AS O
LEFT JOIN _OrderDetailsTotals AS ODT
    ON O.Ordernumber = ODT.Ordernumber
    AND O.location_code = ODT.Location_code;
```